# how to show total files size in a folder by filtering extension without showing each file size

Tags: files, wildcards, disk-usage

`du -hc *zip` shows me total size of zip files in a folder, but it shows also every single file size of the folder. I only need total size.

Is there way to show the total size of a folder without showing single file sizes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 du -ch *zip | grep total
```

Just add a grep statement in the end.

If you are against `grep`, you can use,

```
du -s *zip
-s, --summarize
display only a total for each argument
```

Comment: `du -s *zip` does not work for me and no need of grep anyhow `du -ch *zip` last line itself is total. see my answer. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The `-s` flag summarises each argument, so if you run `du -s *zip` it still runs `du` on each .zip file, summarising each of them. It's very useful for getting a summary of how big a directory is, though.

Answer (score 7):

you can use `du -ch *.zip | tail -1` . last line of `du -ch` is total. If the files have `total.zip` grep total will return that one as well.

Comment: I missed that point. Good catch :)